# How to loop throgh all links in div and collect values from opened fields

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Is it possible to open every link in certain div and collect values of opened fields alltogether in one file or at least terminal output?

I am trying to get list of coordinates from all markers visible on [google map](http://maps.google.com/maps?source=s_q&f=q&hl=lv&geocode=&q=http:%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fmsid%3D207561992958290099079.0004b731f1c645294488e%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml&aq=&sll=56.799934,24.5753&sspn=3.85093,8.64624&ie=UTF8&ll=56.799934,24.5753&spn=3.610137,9.887695&z=7&vpsrc=0&oi=map_misc&ct=api_logo).

```
all_links = b.div(:id, "kmlfolders").links
all_links.each do |link|
   b.link.click
   b.link(:text, "Norādījumi").click
   puts b.text_field(:title, "Galapunkta_adrese").value
end
```

Are there easier or more effective ways how to automatically collect coordinates from all markers?

[image]

Comment: Google Maps API - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/ - easier and more effective (just guessing, I've never tried it).

Comment: You've done it how I would have done it.  If you're looking for something more straightforward or robust, GM API is the way to go.

Comment: If we had a sample of the HTML it might be possible to see what other info exists

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is other data (alt tags? elements invoked via onhover?) in the HTML already that you could pick through, that does seem like the most practical way to iterate through the links, however from what I can see you are not actually making use of the 'link' object inside your loop.  You'd need something more like this I think

```
all_links = b.div(:id, "kmlfolders").links
all_links.each do |thelink|
   b.link(:href => thelink.href).click
   b.link(:text, "Norādījumi").click
   puts b.text_field(:title, "Galapunkta_adrese").value
end
```

Probably using their API is a lot more effective means to get what you want however, it's why folks make API's after all, and if one is available, then using it is almost always best.  Using a test tool as a screen-scraper to gather the info is liable to be a lot harder in the long run than learning how to make some api calls and get the data that way.

for web based api's and Ruby I find the [REST-CLIENT gem](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) works great,  other folks like [HTTP-Party](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not already familiar with Google API, I find it hard for me to dig into API for one particular need. Therefor I made short watir-webdriver script for collecting coordinates of markers on protected google map. Resulting file is used in python script that creates speedcam files for navigation devices.

In this case it's speedcam map maintained and updated by Latvian police, but this script can probably be used with any google map just by replacing url.

```
# encoding: utf-8
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
@b = Watir::Browser.new :ff
#--------------------------------

@b.goto "http://maps.google.com/maps?source=s_q&f=q&hl=lv&geocode=&q=htt%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fmsid%3D207561992958290099079.0004b731f1c645294488e%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml&aq=&sll=56.799934,24.5753&sspn=3.85093,8.64624&ie=UTF8&ll=56.799934,24.5753&spn=3.610137,9.887695&z=7&vpsrc=0&oi=map_misc&ct=api_logo"
@b.div(:id, "kmlfolders").wait_until_present
all_markers = @b.div(:id, "kmlfolders").divs(:class, "fdrlt")
@prev_coordinates = 1
puts "#{all_markers.length} speedcam markers detected"

File.open("list_of_coordinates.txt","w") do |outfile|
all_markers.each do |marker|
    sleep 1
    marker.click
    sleep 1
    description = @b.div(:id => "iw_kml").text
    @b.span(:class, "actbar-text").click
    sleep 2
    coordinates = @b.text_field(:name, "daddr").value
    redo if coordinates == @prev_coordinates
    puts coordinates
    outfile.puts coordinates
    @prev_coordinates = coordinates
end
end

puts "Coordinates saved in file!"

@b.close
```

Works both on Mac OSX 10.7 and Windows7.